# sie/er/es schmeckt oder riecht

Tags: meaning

was ist es  eher üblich benutzt, wenn ich sagen: Die "abc" ist nicht gut. Sie riecht/schmeckt mehr so gut. oder ES riecht/schmeckt nicht gut.
Sowie ich gelernt habe, muss bei dem Wort "riechen" es verwendet werden. Andererseits wurde mir gesagt, dass ich "sie" für "die" benutzen muss.

Was ist denn richtig?

Vielen Dank!

Comment: Der Satz braucht etwas mehr Kontext, denke ich. "Sie riecht mehr so gut" ist kein grammatikalisch korrekter Satz. Soll es "Sie riecht besser" heißen, weil ein Vergleich gemeint ist? Oder soll es "Sie riecht nicht mehr so gut" als zeitliche Änderung dieser Aussage?

Answer (score 6):

Welches Personalpronomen oder welchen Artikel man verwendet, hängt davon ab, was man ausdrücken will.

> Haben wir noch Milch?
> Ne, die roch nicht mehr gut.

> Und das hier ist mein Hund.
> Boah, der riecht ja gar nicht gut.

> Ich habe ein neues Auto.
> Das riecht voll gut.

> Ich mag meine Freundin/meinen Freund, sie/er riecht immer voll gut.
> Ich mag keine Tiere, denn sie riechen nie gut.

Wenn wir dagegen eine generelle Aussage tätigen wollen, meistens wenn wir nicht genau wissen, woher der Geruch kommt, verwenden wir *es*:

> Es riecht hier gar nicht gut.
> Ja, der Syphon ist undicht.

Comment: kann ich für die Sachen "Personalpronomen" verwenden. zum Beispiel. Sie riecht nicht mehr gut/sie ist abgelaufen. (vorher wurde Die Milch erwähnt)?

Comment: Ja das geht auch.